# Selenium: best way to tackle a dynamically changing page?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm building my test suite using Cucumber + Selenium on Java.

Now the problem is, upon user registration a series of modal dialogs are displayed before the account is actually created, but they don't always show up in the same order or containing the same elements. So, let's say that once you get the "tell us your real name" dialog first in the series and the next time you get a "pick your hobbies from this list" first. There are about 5 dialogs in the series and there's no way to tell which one will show up, they're random.

Is there any strategy I can use to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

You code will need to cover these complexities with if-else statements.
Shouldn't be too.complex

Answer (score 1):

We can use the switch case and if else logic for the text coming in the drop down.
Try to create dynamic xpath with the questions which will be useful, if any one the required questions is shown, Script will pass